# GetResponse() Error in the PayPal functionality when trying to checkout

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

So I'm following the [WingTip Toy tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal), and I know its sort of old but it was error free until I got to the point where I needed to checkout with PayPal using the sandbox developing tool

This is the code where the error occurs

```
//Retrieve the Response returned from the NVP API call to PayPal.
        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
        string result;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
```

And this is the error im getting when i run it

```
[ProtocolViolationException: You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.]
```

Please note I'm a beginner

Edit: The full code is here

```
public string HttpCall(string NvpRequest)
    {
        string url = pEndPointURL;

        string strPost = NvpRequest + "&" + buildCredentialsNVPString();
        strPost = strPost + "&BUTTONSOURCE=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(BNCode);

        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        objRequest.Timeout = Timeout;
        objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;





        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                myWriter.Write(strPost);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // No logging for this tutorial.
        }

        //Retrieve the Response returned from the NVP API call to PayPal.
        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
        string result;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you write the request body?

Comment: @peter added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
```

What are you trying to do here? The framework sets the content length automatically. The content length is in bytes but you have given the number of characters.

That's why the error complains: You have written a different number of characters than you said you would write.

Delete that line.

Your code would become a lot simpler if you used `HttpClient`. Should be about 5 lines.

Comment: I commented that line and I built and ran the application, Im getting the same error and its breaking at this line

 HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();

Comment: Please post the full updated code and the exception ToString output.

Comment: Actually the error changed to Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. I'll go to the original Microsoft comments i think they posted something about that, commenting it mightve solved the issue!